# MySQL recovery procedure

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

After the server die, I have "old" HD (it is external now) with sock file and data files in mysql directory.
Where I should find information how to restore the data in fresh installed MySQL?

What will happens if I replace files and folders brutal way?

Comment: You need to expand your question and explain clearer. At the moment, this question makes little sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy the files from the old HD to the new MySQL datadir MySQL will pick them up and start crash recovery. There is a chance the crash recovery is successful, then you can use MySQL database normally.

If crash recovery is unsuccessful try to start MySQL again with innodb_force_recovery=4 option in my.cnf. If MySQL starts you have to dump all databases you need with mysqldump. Then import the dump into the fresh instance of MySQL.